# Regularity of a rational function of several real variables

Tags: real-analysis

This is a simple looking question. Given is a real valued rational function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^N$. It is known:
(i) $f$ is regular on an open convex set $C$ from $\mathbb{R}^N$, that is, $f = p/q$, with $p, q$ polynomials and $q$ is not vanishing on $C;$
(ii) for a point of $x_1$ from the boundary $\partial C$ of $C$ the function $f$ has a limit along any ray from $C$ leading to $x_1$ and this limit is independent of the ray direction. More precisely, for any $x_0$ from $C$ the limit $f(tx_0 + (1 - t)x_1)$, as $t$ tends to zero, exists and is independent of $x_0.$
Conjecture: The function $f$ is regular in $x_1.$
Remark. Should this prove to be false strengthen our assumption to hold for all points of the boundary. Is the conjecture true then?
Thanks in advance to anybody helping to prove or disprove this, Kresimir Veselic.

Comment: By "$f$ is regular at $x_1$" you mean that $f=r/s$ for some polynomials $r,s$ with $s(x_1)\not= 0$ ?